# Does Mathematica have a built-in n-dimensional hypervolume indicator?

Tags: computational-geometry

Mathematica has so many functions hidden away in obscure packages that I thought I'd ask before starting to code one myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`RegionMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html)?

Comment: That seems like an excellent starting point! I still need to figure out how to represent the region itself, but below the main article there are several suggested functions that seem helpful. Thanks!